# PHP Memcached Session Locking Enable

Tags: php, session, locking, memcached

I use "memcached" to store php sessions.
It is important, that request must be synchronously (to avoid duplicate transactions or operations), but while using "memcached" session, "session locking" not works.

is some method to lock "memcached" session until one request will executed?

Comment: Can you provide more info on that ? I don't understand your question I think.

Answer (score 1):

There's nothing built in no, but you can write stuff yourself to make your code atomic.

```
$key = 'lockable_key_name';
$lockkey = $key.'##LOCK';

if($memcached->add($lockkey, '', 60)) {
    $storedvalue = $memcached->get($key);

    // do something with $storedvalue
    $memcached->set($key, $newvalue);

    // release
    $memcached->delete($lockkey);
}
```

In your code you could check for the lock by doing:

```
if(!$memcached->get($lockkey)) {
    // then do something
}
```

If the get method returns false then there's no lock, or the operation has hung and passed the 60 second timeout specified in the add call above.

Answer (score 1):

Since you were asking for credible/official sources:

The memcached extension supports session locking since version 3.0.4, according to the changelog document on the PECL extension page: http://pecl.php.net/package-info.php?package=memcache&version=3.0.4

If you happen to run an earlier version (it means that your version of the memcached extension is more than 4 years old), you are out of luck and should upgrade.

Comment: session handler is configured in php.ini:
`session.save_handler = memcache
session.save_path = "tcp://192.168.*.*:*"`
PHP uses php_memcache.dll (Win Server 2008,php 5.3)
switch to PECL is good idea.
thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe try something like `$(field_name)_is_locked = true` when you start then when you are done `$(field_name)_is_locked = false` and pass the variable to the server when you update it.